# Emit to DynamicAssembly with Roslyn RC

Tags: c#, roslyn

From many examples of compiling a Roslyn SyntaxTree, I have seen code such as:

```
[... create tree and compilation ...]
var assembly = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.DefineDynamicAssembly(new AssemblyName("foo"), AssemblyBuilderAccess.RunAndCollect);
var module = assembly.DefineDynamicModule("foo");

var result = compilation.Emit(module);
```

But when I try to do this in the current Roslyn released with Visual Studio 2015 RC, I see no `Emit()` which takes a module. I need to write to a stream and load it into a regular `AppDomain`-locked `Assembly`.

I then see this answer from Tomas Matousek: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22977158

Where he says that this has been removed because it was "problematic".

I am having difficulty finding any other information about this on the Internet. Does anyone know if:

- There is another way in Roslyn to compile into an assembly that can be garbage collected?
- Or this will be supported in the final release of VS / Roslyn?
- Where I should direct this question if nobody here knows (had trouble finding an official, active Roslyn forum)?

Comment: The official, active Roslyn site [is on github](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn). If you want to start a discussion about something, create an issue.

Comment: It's not possible within Roslyn until the CLR supports collectible assemblies. You can vote for them here: http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/6120992-support-for-collectible-assemblies

On GitHub: https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/issues/552

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As svick and JoshVarty said in the comments, this is currently not possible. I also created an issue (https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/2621) for this that might or might not end up with some more information from the Microsoft team.